# Swift. Как обновить TableViewController не перезапуская приложение?

Tags: swift, xcode

После добавления данных о дне рождении в AddBirthdayViewController таблица BirthdayViewController не обновляется (хотя метод reloadData() вызван!). Как исправить? Необходимо, чтобы СРАЗУ ЖЕ после нажатия на кнопку Save данные не только записывались в Core Data (это уже реализовано), но и сразу отображались в таблице.

На данном этапе (код ниже) данные появляются только после перезапуска приложения.

Добавление данных:

```
class AddBirthdayViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet var firstNameTextField: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet var lastNameTextField: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet var birthdatePicker: UIDatePicker!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            birthdatePicker.maximumDate = Date()
        }
        @IBAction func saveTapped (_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
            let firstName = firstNameTextField.text ?? ""
            let lastName = lastNameTextField.text ?? ""
            let birthdate = birthdatePicker.date
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
            let newBirthday = Birthday (context: context)
            newBirthday.firstName = firstName
            newBirthday.lastName = lastName
            newBirthday.birthdate = birthdate as Date?
            newBirthday.birthdayId = UUID () .uuidString
            do {
                try context.save ()
                let message = "Сегодня \(firstName) \(lastName) празднует день рождения!"
                let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
                content.body = message
                content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
                var dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month, .day], from: birthdate)
                dateComponents.hour = 19
                let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
                if let identifier = newBirthday.birthdayId {
                let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
                let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
                    center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
                }
            } catch let error {
                print ("There is an error \(error)")
            }
                dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        @IBAction func cancelTapped (_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }
```

Таблица, где они должны отображаться:

```
class BirthdaysTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var birthdays = [Birthday] ()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter ()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .full
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
    }

    override func viewWillAppear (_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear (true)
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest = Birthday.fetchRequest() as NSFetchRequest<Birthday>
        let sortDescriptor1 = NSSortDescriptor (key: "lastName", ascending: true)
        let sortDescriptor2 = NSSortDescriptor (key: "firstName", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2]
        do {
            birthdays = try context.fetch (fetchRequest)
        } catch let error {
            print ("There is error: \(error)")
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return birthdays.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "birthdayCellIdentifier", for: indexPath)
        let birthday = birthdays[indexPath.row]
        let firstName = birthday.firstName ?? ""
        let lastName = birthday.lastName ?? ""
        cell.textLabel?.text = firstName + " " + lastName

        if let date = birthday.birthdate as Date? {
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        } else {
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = " "
        }
        return cell
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if birthdays.count > indexPath.row {
            let birthday = birthdays [indexPath.row]
            if let identifier = birthday.birthdayId {
                let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
                center.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers:
                   [identifier])
            }
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
            context.delete(birthday)
            birthdays.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            do {
                try context.save ()
            } catch let error {
                print ("There is an error \(error)")
            }
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А как происходит переход на AddBirthdayViewController ?

Comment: Модальное представление

Comment: Я имел ввиду, переход через сигвей или через код, что-то типа такого storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: ...) .... present(newViewController, animated: ....)

Comment: так как все разрешилось? подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы показываете `AddBirthdayViewController` в модальном представлении прямо из `BirthdaysTableViewController`, то это значит, что после его закрывания (нажатия на Save или Cancel) и возврата к `BirthdaysTableViewController` его метод `viewWillAppear` не вызывается (из-за показа в модальном представлении), стало быть и таблица не обновляется.

Вы можете делать следующее для обновления данных при возврате из модального вью контроллера:

- в `AddBirthdayViewController` объявить переменную `var saveCompletion: (() -> Void)?`
- использовать ее при закрытии вью контроллера `dismiss(animated: true, completion: saveCompletion)`
- в `BirthdaysTableViewController` сделать так (я сократил код)

  ```
  override func viewWillAppear (_ animated: Bool) {
      super.viewWillAppear (true)

      loadData()
  }

  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
      guard let addBirthdayVC = segue.destination as? AddBirthdayViewController else {
          return
      }

      addBirthdayVC.saveCompletion = {
          self.loadData()
      }
  }

  func loadData() {
      let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
      let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
      let fetchRequest = Birthday.fetchRequest() as NSFetchRequest<Birthday>
      let sortDescriptor1 = NSSortDescriptor (key: "lastName", ascending: true)
      let sortDescriptor2 = NSSortDescriptor (key: "firstName", ascending: true)
      fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2]

      do {
          birthdays = try context.fetch (fetchRequest)
      } catch let error {
          print ("There is error: \(error)")
      }

      tableView.reloadData()
  }
  ```

**Дополнение**

Так как у вас в проекте между `BirthdaysTableViewController` и `AddBirthdayViewController` еще `UINavigationController` (который можно и убрать, тогда мой первоначальный код заработает, но придется добавлять вручную navigation bar), то можно сделать так

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard let navigationController = segue.destination as? UINavigationController else {
            return
        }

        guard let addBirthdayVC = navigationController.viewControllers.first as? AddBirthdayViewController else {
            return
        }

        addBirthdayVC.saveCompletion = {
            self.loadData()
        }
    }
```

**Дополнение 2**

Замечание касательно работы со временем - так как вы используете тут даты, то нужно быть внимательными касательно часовых поясов - вы получаете дату из пикера в UTC 0, в то время как при выводе дата по умолчанию выводится в текущем часовом поясе на устройстве, в результате вы можете получить другую дату при выводе (+/- 1 день) поэтому при форматировании тут возможно стоит сразу указать часовой пояс для вывода даты в неизменном виде

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
```

Comment: schmidt9, большое спасибо! Полученный ответ меня полностью устраивает!

Comment: @Антон в таком случае поставьте возле него галку

Comment: прошу прощения: с выводом о работоспособности кода я поторопился. Возможно, я что-то сделал не так, но после внедрения Ваших правок данные по-прежнему не обновляются

Comment: @Антон метод loadData вызывается после возврата из AddBirthdayViewController?

Comment: Метод loadData() вызывается внутри viewWillAppear, как и написано у Вас

Comment: @Антон а это вы добавили? `addBirthdayVC.saveCompletion = { self.loadData() }`

Comment: Конечно, внутрь функции prepare

Comment: @Антон а это? "использовать ее при закрытии вью контроллера dismiss(animated: true, completion: saveCompletion)"

Comment: Я добавил абсолютно всё. Есть ли возможность отправить Вам исправленный код? Так как сейчас мы просто перебираем все возможные варианты того, что я мог пропустить и не добавить, тогда как причина может заключаться в другом

Comment: @Антон заливайте куда-нибудь тестовый проект, гляну

Comment: В частности, между TableView и AddBirthday у меня стоит Navigation Controller. Может, он лишний?

Comment: @Антон о пикантные подробности. Ну заливайте проект глянем

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wOZT1EqYr8-jftBW8KSjmuY04WG_KezW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Антон вообще рекомендую чаще пользоваться отладчиком и смотреть по точкам останова, вызываются ли нужные методы и что содержится в переменных

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь! Всё заработало именно так, как нужно!